# How do you fill in an array with random integers in the constructor? (2D array)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Accidents{
    static final int DAYS  = 31;
    static final int HOURS = 24;

    private int[][] accidents = new int[DAYS][HOURS];

    public Accidents(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        accidents[DAYS][HOURS] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

**This apparently does not work. I have tried using a tester.I want to know how should I write the constructor so that it generates random integers from 0 to 9??  Thank you.**

**You can ignore what is below.**

```
  public int totalAccidents(){
     int total = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<accidents.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<accidents[0].length; j++){
           total += accidents[i][j]; 
        }
     }
        return total;     
  }


  public int mostAccidents(){
  int sum = 0;
  int max = 0;
     for (int i=0;i<24;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<accidents.length; j++){
        sum += accidents[j][i];
        }
        if (sum> max)
           max = sum;
     }
     return max;
  }


  public void printArray(){
     for(int j=0; j<accidents.length; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<accidents[0].length; k++){
           System.out.print(accidents[j][k]+"   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is only setting the last value in the 2d array. You will need to loop through your array like in your `totalAccidents' function to set each value in the array. So something like this should be in your constructor:

```
for(int i=0; i<accidents.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<accidents[0].length; j++){
       accidents[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }
  }
```